# Div alignments in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to have an alignment like in the image based on the number of sub divs, using CSS/HTML and Bootstrap.

1. Full width can hold upto 3 divs (i.e. .container)
2. If only 2 divs are shown they should be center aligned.

As of now, all the divs would align to left or right.

What would be an easy way to achieve this with CSS/HTML?  Not sure what keywords I should search for on Google about this - as there are just a lot of articles talking about centering divs.

[image]

Comment: have you tried flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D,  I do code a lot. CSS doesn't offer it out of the box (unless it's something I don't know) hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `div` to `inline-block` and your wrapper to `text-align: center`:

```css
.wrapper { text-align: center; }
.wrapper div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With that CSS, put your divs like so (floats first):

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. You could also float right, then left, then center. The important thing is that the floats come before the "main" center section

P.P.S. You often want last inside `#container` this snippet: `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` which will extend #container vertically to contain both side floats instead of taking its height only from `#center` and possibly allowing the sides to protrude out the bottom.

Comment: This couples your style and dom too tightly, making future changes such a burden...